# Scroll View with transparent background (Objective-c Mac OS X)

Tags: objective-c, scrollview, transparent, macos

I have a Scroll View in my Mac app with a white background but I want the background to be completely transparent. I changed the opacity of the background to 0 but that doesn't seem to help, so I added an image of my settings and i was hoping you maybe were able to see the problem

[image: http://www.servimg.com/image_preview.php?i=8&u=12413370]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try unchecking the "Draw Background" box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this for a 10.7 App? If so it should just work out of the box. If you are doing 10.6 or earlier you might have to implement your own custom scrollbar or use a toolkit like Chamelion,etc to get the effect you are looking for. Only 10.7 has overlay scrollbars by default, prior to this the OS scrollbars subtracted area from the content view to dedicate to scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, you just set the background to the clearColor. It seems logical the same would apply to the Mac.

Comment: Yeah, That's what I thought too. Maybe there's some kind of bug because I tried to change the background color to black and it remains white for some reason.